# How to add an object to a list created within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm learning about classes. I created an Item class which defines statistics for an item, for example a sword. I also created a Player class, with an inventory for items. I added a super_sword to the Item class and now I would like to add super_sword to Player inventory. I receive the following error:

```
        line 16, in add_item
    item.append(inventory)
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'append'
```

My code:

```
class Item:
    def item_stats():
        base_dmg = 0
        magic_dmg = 0

#--- Create an item super_sword and assign damage attributes ---#
super_sword = Item() 
super_sword.base_dmg = 10
super_sword.magic_dmg = 12

class Player:

    inventory = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        item.append(inventory)

#--- Create some_character and add super_sword to its inventory ---#
some_character = Player()
some_character.add_item(super_sword)
```

Comment: Please return to your instructional materials on `append` to learn the usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

```
item.append(inventory)
```

You are trying to append inventory to the list item. It needs to be swapped:

```
inventory.append(item)
```

Comment: Thank you, my brain needs, more coffee, I don't know why I tried appending inventory intead of the item... Now it comes back with NameError: name 'inventory' is not defined. I thought that if I define inventory within the class, it will be available to the add_item function.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could answer.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to define inventory so that it is callable from the add_item function? Right now it tells me that inventory is not defined, even though it is defined within the class

Comment: You would want to add an `__init__` function where you can declare `self.inventory = []` so that it is callable throughout the entire class

Comment: Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

@holden has partially answered your question but it needs to be:

```
self.inventory.append(item)
```

Also the way you have it declared now **inventory** is a class variable and so will be shared by all instances of the Player class, which is not likely what you want.

Assuming that each instance of Player is intended to have its own inventory, it needs to be defined inside an **__init__()** method for the Player class. Like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = []
```

Inside the init method you would also include any other intializations that your Player instances might need.